# Is there a way to pass an empty string to a `.where("candidates.resume_template_id IN ("#{template_ids.join(", ")})")?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am currently working on a project in rails and i have this scope:

```
scope :for_resume_templates, ->(resume_template_ids = []) { joins("INNER JOIN templates ON candidates.resume_id =templates.id").where("templates.resume_template_id IN (#{resume_template_ids.join(", ")})")}
```

Currently, i am submitting a form with an optional select box for the `resume_template_ids`. it used to work in Rails 4 but I am currently migrating to rails 5 and it throws this error when `resume_template_ids` is empty.

Error:

```
PG::SyntaxError - ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: ...ed') AND 1=0 AND (policies.policy_template_id IN ()) ORDER B...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using the active-record query language helpers for this, which would look like:

```
scope :for_resume_templates, ->(resume_template_ids = []) { joins("INNER JOIN templates ON candidates.resume_id =templates.id").where(templates: {resume_template_id: resume_template_ids}) }
```

Something to be aware of is that the pattern you're using in the initial code is subject to SQL injection attack because you're directly interpolating variables into SQL. This would be flagged as insecure by a static security code analysis tool like brakeman. Using the built-in helpers where possible helps for security as well, by automatically preventing against SQL injection (either through escaping the input or via parameterized queries) as well as handling empty array and nil cases.

I'd also recommend setting up associations and using the built-in `joins(association_name)` helpers, to reduce duplication if you do the same join in other places. This would look like:

```
# add associations
class Candidate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :templates, foreign_key: :resume_id
  # or `has_one :template, foreign_key: :resume_id` depending on whether you expect one or several. The join will be the same either way.
  scope :for_resume_templates, ->(resume_template_ids = []) { joins(:templates).where(templates: {resume_template_id: resume_template_ids}) }
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, you saved me a ton on hours work trying to find a fix.